# Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I've seen several variants of this problem involving android, powermock, bytebuddy-downloads-gone-wrong and likely others. I don't think my problem is related to powermock or android since I'm using neither. Below is the test class, with irrelevant tests omitted.

```
    public class TournamentsTests {

    private ToornamentClient client;
    private HashMap<String,String> params;
    private HashMap<String,String> headers;

    private TournamentRequest tournamentRequest = new TournamentRequest();
    private TournamentDetails tournamentDetails = new TournamentDetails();
    @Before
    public void Setup() throws IOException {
        client = new ToornamentClient(System.getenv("KEY"),System.getenv("CLIENT"),System.getenv("SECRET"));
        client.authorize();

        headers = new HashMap<>();
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("disciplines","overwatch");

        tournamentDetails.setParticipantType(ParticipantType.TEAM);
        tournamentDetails.setName("OWL Season 1");
        tournamentDetails.setSize(144);
        tournamentDetails.setDiscipline("overwatch");

        tournamentRequest.setDiscipline("overwatch");
        tournamentRequest.setOrganization("Blizzard Entertainment");
        tournamentRequest.setWebsite("http://www.overwatchleague.com");
        tournamentRequest.setMatchFormat(MatchFormat.BO3);
        tournamentRequest.setPrize("$500,000-$1,000,000");
        tournamentRequest.setSize(144);
        tournamentRequest.setName("OWL Season 1");
        tournamentRequest.setParticipantType(ParticipantType.TEAM);

    }
    @AfterEach
    public void CleanUp(){
        headers.clear();
    }

    @Test
    public void createTournamentTest(){
       Mockito.when(client.tournaments().createTournament(tournamentRequest)).thenReturn(tournamentDetails);


    }

}
```

The single test above is the one i'm trying to mock since it is intended to insert via the api this library is intended for. I'm not sure if powermock is part of the solution since i'm unclear on what it does, but feel free to help me solve this with it. My build.gradle file looks like this:

```
group 'ch.wisv'
version '0.1'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    baseName = 'toornament-client'
    version = '0.1'
}

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.8.7'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.8.7'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.7'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.6.0'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.18.0'
}
```

I don't think anything is out of place here either, and checked in my IDE that dependencies like bytebuddy and objenesis were downloaded.

A few things I've tried are:

- A @Mock annotation over the variable "client"
- ToornamentClient client = Mockito.mock(ToornamentClient.class)
- Toornaments caller = Mockito.mock(client.tournaments().getClass())